# Sorting a NSArrayController backed NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have a NSArrayController and a NSTableView. They show tracks from iTunes. I can sort the list by clicking in the header.

Is there a way to set up a default sort descriptor for the table view so it sorts for albums every time the user launches the app?

I tried to set the sortDescriptor on the array controller and the table view but that changes nothing.

Thank you

Edit: The answer is right. But it needs a NSArray:

```
- (NSArray *)mainSortDescriptor {

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"album" ascending:YES], 
            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"trackNumber" ascending:YES], 
            nil];
```

}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to bind the array controller's sort descriptor, you have to bind it *to* something. You can put this in your application delegate, for example:

```
- (NSArray *)tracksSortDescriptors {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObject:
             [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"albumName"
                                           ascending:YES]];
}
```

Then you can set up the binding in IB as

```
Bind to: MyAppDelegate  
Model Key Path: tracksSortDescriptors
```

<sub>EDITED. I forgot, when translating this from PyObjC, that I was returning a list. Oops.</sub>

Comment: Thats right. I tried something similar but it didn't work. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: @Josh Caswell I get the following error: [<NSViewController 0x100147980> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tracksSortDescriptors.
Any ideas?

Comment: @DomVinyard You've bound to the view controller instead of app delegate. No problem, simply implement the method `tracksSortDescriptors ` in your view controller instead.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this, didn't quite work - resorted on each app start, but not while the app was running.

Eventually, I noticed that in my NSArrayController object, the following box was unticked (argh!):

"Auto rearrange content"

...so, FYI to anyone who has the same problem: make sure that box is ON :)